# Вызов хранимой процедуры SQL Server из MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server

Есть база на MySQL и база на MS SQL Server, требуется из первой вызвать процедуру во второй. Возможно ли это без установки дополнительного ПО, плагинов и т.п.? Linked Server работает только в одну сторону?

Comment: Из mssql можно сделать вызов, из mysql врядли. Можно создать вьюшку или таблицу, и навесить на неё триггер вставки. Вставляя в таблицу будет вызыватся триггер.

Comment: Зачем вам вообще mysql?..

Comment: @PavelMayorov сайт на MySQL, информационная система предприятия на MS SQL, данные гоняются туда-сюда хранимками а-ля самописная репликация

Comment: Лучше записывайте лог изменений в отдельную таблицу, после чего выгружайте изменения пакетами.

Comment: А еще лучше - откройте для себя веб-сервисы.

Comment: в данном случае поздно что-либо открывать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашёл приемлемое решение в [этом посте](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/51047/103166). Заворачиваем вызов процедуры SQL Server в функцию PHP и вызываем эту функцию из MySQL, передавая ей необходимые параметры:

> The only way I can think of doing this is to create a MySQL trigger that calls a User Defined Function that executes an external application and passes the new data to it. The external application would have to connect to the SQL Server database and push the data to it.
>
> ```
> DELIMITER @@
>
> CREATE TRIGGER Test_Trigger 
> AFTER INSERT ON MyTable 
> FOR EACH ROW
> BEGIN
>
> DECLARE cmd CHAR(255);
> DECLARE result int(10);
> SET cmd=CONCAT('/usr/bin/php ', 'home/sync/send_to_sql_server.php f1=', NEW.f1, ' f2=', NEW.f2);
> SET result = sys_exec(cmd);
>
> END;
> @@
> DELIMITER ;
> ```

Comment: FOR EACH ROW вызов внешней программы... удачи

Comment: @PavelMayorov это же не для табличных строк FOR EACH, а для вставляемых

Comment: Каждая табличная строка когда-то была вставлена.

Comment: ну вставляются они по одной и не так часто